# Location tracking in foreground service while screen if off

Tags: android, service, background, location

I'm trying to get location updates while phone screen is off. I'm using foreground service and everything is working as it should even in the background. Up until phone screen turns off. Then I stop receiving location updates. Any thoughts? I know my service is working because I get other data without any issues. Permissions is not an issue here. 'Allow all the time' is selected. When I turn the screen on even with locked phone I start getting updates again. Any ideas? I seems that requestLocationUpdates are put to sleep when device screen is off. Battery saver is turned off, app is not optimized or restricted by OS.

I've created location manager class that I call from inside my foreground service:

```
class LocationManager(val context: Context) : LocationCallback() {

    private var request: LocationRequest
    private var locationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    var listener: ((result: LocationResult?)->Unit)? = null

    init {
        locationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
        request = createRequest()
    }

    private fun createRequest(): LocationRequest =
        LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 100).apply {
            setGranularity(Granularity.GRANULARITY_PERMISSION_LEVEL)
            setWaitForAccurateLocation(true)
        }.build()

    fun startLocationTracking() {
       locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, this, Looper.getMainLooper())
    }



    fun stopLocationTracking() {
        locationClient.flushLocations()
        locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this)
    }

    override fun onLocationResult(location: LocationResult) {
        listener?.invoke(location)
    }

    override fun onLocationAvailability(availability: LocationAvailability) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that we need to use different method in order to get those values even with the screen off. We need to use location tracking that provides intent responses.

```
private lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent

    fun startLocationTracking() {
       //Instead of this:
       //locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, this, Looper.getMainLooper())
//use this:
val intent = Intent(context, RecordingService::class.java)
intent.action = "UPDATELOCATION_ACTION"
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)

    }
```

In foreground service:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    if (intent.action.equals("UPDATELOCATION_ACTION")) {
        val locationResult = LocationResult.extractResult(intent)
        recordsManager.saveLocation(locationResult)
    }
...
}
```

To remove updates:

```
locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(pendingIntent)
```